# ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

**Error while merging dex archives:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.**

The code worked properly before add react-native-firebase/admob. But after adding that library build fails. When i removing the react-navigation built. Why these two libraries cannot use same app?

*Here is my app.json file and the build.gradle files.*

````
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.27",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.29",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16"
  },

buildscript {
   ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much and finally I have fixed the problem. I changed the code as

```
defaultConfig {
// ...
multiDexEnabled true }
```

I added multiDexEnabled true line to defaultconfig in android/app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Multidex in android  if the number of method references in a .dex file exceed 64K . To know how to use Multidex please see it [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)